Jenkins Version - Jenkins 2.462.1 (facing issue with HTTP Proxy in Global Config)
But in the New version 2.462.1 it is moved to the Global config section
Previously, we didn’t face any issues, but now whenever we clone the code, it’s going through the proxy and getting cloned successfully. However, the problem is that we have multiple jobs across different environments, and the proxy we’re using is specific to the lower environment. As a result, for the production and beta environments, the cloning is failing because it’s using the same proxy as the lower environment.
enter image description here
How can we set a proxy at the node level for each environment, so that each node uses its respective proxy when cloning the code, instead of using the global proxy?
By the way give me solution for freestyle…as we are using Free style jobs…
we are using swarm to connect our nodes using script below.
`#!/bin/bash
export https_proxy=http://
export http_proxy=http://
# Start jenkins-slave service

{% for k,v in jenkins_slave_env_vars.items() %}
export {{ k }}={{ v }}
{% endfor %}

/usr/bin/java -jar \
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts={{ non_ProxyHosts }} \
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/oxygen \
"{{ jenkins_slave_jar_dir }}/swarm-client.jar" \
-master "{{ jenkins_master_url }}" \
-name "{{ jenkins_slave_name }}-{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}" \
-fsroot "{{ jenkins_slave_working_dir }}" \
{% for item in jenkins_slave_labels %}-labels "{{ item }}" {% endfor %} \
-username "{{ jenkins_master_remote_user }}" -password "{{ jenkins_master_remote_user_pass }}" \
-executors {{ jenkins_slave_executors }} {% if jenkins_master_tunnel|length %}-tunnel {{ jenkins_master_tunnel }}{% endif %}`

The Jenkins nodes are connecting successfully, and we are using individual proxies specific to each environment. How can we configure Jenkins to use these agent level proxies when cloning repositories?
